# Why is this throwing System.FormatException:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, exception, formatexception

Why does this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("08/31/2017")
```

throw an System.FormatException but not this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("09/12/2017")
```

If you need more information please ask and I will update or comment.  I have no clue what is causing this issue, so I don't know what details you need.

Comment: Probably because it is interpreting the date as day first and then month. You need to use DateTime.ParseExact

Comment: Because American way of writing dates is invalid unless you specify custom formatting.

Comment: Most likely because the second is being interpreted as day 9 of month 12 ( December 12, 2017, a valid date) while the first is being interpreted as day 8 of month 31,  2017 and there is no 31st month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default order for this date format on your computers culture is Day/Month/Year, as 31 is not a valid month it fails. If you want this order, you need to provide the format with it:

```
var x = DateTime.ParseExact("08/31/2017", "MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: trying this out.

Comment: working now. Thanks